# Back Button Child View not going back to previous activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

I am building a Login sequence along with a sign-up and reset password, using firebase. Sign up activity is declared to populate at launch. I am having trouble when clicking (from the signup activity) the back button on a reset password activity, as follows. 
OPENS APP..... Sign up launches (Im already a registered user so I click login button) --> LoginActivity (I forgot password so I click reset button) ---> Reset password. Reset password has a back button which should take me back to login activity from which I clicked from but instead the app closes. I was thinking this may have something to do with activity stacks and was reading the documentation below.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. From the login activity, when I clicked the "Forgot Password" button an intent was started to open the reset password activity. Which was followed by `finish();` I believe the back button from the reset password activity was not working because the Login activity was killed by the system. So instead I used `onPause();` and issue was resolved. Tested it twice with `onPause();` and 
`finish();`here is the code from the login activity.class

```
btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ResetPasswordActivity.class));
            onPause();
        }
    });
```